# how to prevent a event in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, tinymce

i have a problem working with the tinyMCE (thanks for this superb documentation!! *irony*)

all i'm searching for is a similar method to jQuerys event.preventDefault() but i want to stop the events fired by the editor.

i tried to use the `execcommand_callback: function(editorID,elem,event)` attribute at the initialization but all i get is a string (editorID), a html node (elem) and another string which contains the name of the current executed event, no event object.
I could manipulate the node where the command will be executed but this wont help me preventing the event.

To disable all Buttons or the whole editor is not an option, any ideas? is this even possible?

i googled the whole weekend and everyone wants to disable the buttons :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those callbacks are not "real" browser events.

Try `return true` to stop calling next callback in chain.

Comment: omg thanks a lot!! i just tried returning false. And i know its not a browser event, but i assumed that a method to stop a editor fired event exists, it does... somehow...